# How to configure CakePHP 3.x to use Amazon SES SMTP to send out emails?

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, smtp, cakephp-3.0

I have successfully created my SMTP credentials in AWS SES.

I have lifted my restrictions.

I have used the [command line](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html) to test if my credentials are okay.

They are.

I am using CakePHP 3.2 but still unable to send out my emails.

The region I use is US West Oregon. The host is `email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## How to test if credentials are okay via Command Line

1. Open up your server terminal and type `echo -n "YOUR SMTP USERNAME" | base64`
2. Copy paste the output somewhere. You will need it. The output should end with `=`
3. Repeat step 1 and 2 for `YOUR SMTP PASSWORD`
4. Copy paste the following into a text file but replace `<whatever>` as you deem fit.

Like this:

```
AFTER 220 .... PASTE THE LINE BELOW:
EHLO <example.com>

AFTER 250 Ok PASTE THE LINE BELOW:
AUTH LOGIN

AFTER 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6:
<YOUR SMTP USERNAME encoded as base64 from step 1>

AFTER 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6:
<YOUR SMTP PASSWORD encoded as base64 from step 3>

AFTER 235 Authentication successful.
MAIL FROM:<yourverifiedemail@example.com>

AFTER 250 Ok
RCPT TO:<yourverifiedemail@example.com>

AFTER 250 Ok
DATA

AFTER 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>    
Subject:Hello from Amazon SES!

This email was sent using the Amazon SES SMTP interface.
.
```

5. Type `openssl s_client -crlf -quiet -connect email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:465` into your terminal
6. Follow the instructions in the text file.

Once ascertained that credentials are good, now configure your cakephp 3.x

## Configure Cake 3.x

- Open up your `config/app.php`
- Find `EmailTransport` and add a new transport below default

Like this:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Mail',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 25,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => null,
    ],
    // START of what you need to add!!
    'AWS_SES' =>[
        'className' => 'Smtp', 
        'host' => 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', 
        'port' => 587, // this is very important to be 587!! 
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'YOUR SMTP USERNAME',
        'password' => 'YOUR SMTP PASSWORD',
        'tls' => true, // this is also very important!!
    ]
    // END of what you need to add!!
],
```

- Now look for `Email` in `app.php` and add a new profile below default

Like this:

```
'Email' => [
    'default' => [
        'transport' => 'default',
        'from' => 'you@localhost',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    ],
// START of what you need to add!
    'production' => [
        'transport' => 'AWS_SES',
        //'log' => true,
    ]
// END of what you need to add!
],
```

- That's all for configuration!
- Just call `$email = new Email('production');` at the appropriate place that you want.